# Game Center no longer works after Recent Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I have an old Objective C project, which uses Game Center, but after a recent update, Game Center no longer works and when I press the GMC button, I get the attached error. ScreenShot Below.

please help solving this problem and i am facing an error as well while making a build of that app.

this is what i got .

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Comment: You didn't attach a screenshot.

Comment: codesign error means it has to do with your certs/provision profiles. not to do with Gamecenter at all.